# JQuery Additional Questions Fade Effect

Tags: php, jquery, html, fade

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.bopa').load('accounts.php');
  },30000);
});
```

Hi guys! Me again. So I got back to this stuff and I realized that this is JQuery. It maybe possible for me to put a fade effect somewhere there. I just don't konw where. Is it actually possible if so please tell me where. The accounts php actualy contains something like

```
$command=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages order by rand()    limit 1");
```

now it works every 3 seconds the content changes. I am trying it on text first so that it'd be easier. Later on I'm planning to do it on pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a callback function to the AJAX request you're making:

```
$('.bopa').load('accounts.php');
```

Could change to:

```
//start by fading-out the element(s)
$('.bopa').fadeOut(250, function () {
    //continue by loading the new content now that the element(s) has/have faded-out
    $(this).load('accounts.php', function () {

        //now that the new content has loaded, fade the element(s) back in
        $(this).fadeIn(250);
    });
});
```

This also takes advantage of the callback functions for the jQuery animation functions used (`.fadeIn()`/`.fadeOut()`).

Comment: Glad to help, if it answered your question could you accept the answer by clicking the check-mark next to the answer score?